# How to resolve /etc/mtab symlink permission error when using podman additional image store?

Tags: docker, container, podman

**Summary:** I am attempting to use additional image stores with `podman` on an Ubuntu server, but I am experiencing permissions issues. The shared image does show up when running `podman images`. When I try to run it, I get `Error: creating /etc/mtab symlink: permission denied`. When I use `sudo`, as a sudoer, it attempts to pull the remote image rather than using the locally shared image. Other users also cannot run the shared image.

My approach is based on two blogs:

[Exploring additional image stores in Podman](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/image-stores-podman)

[5 underused Podman features to try now](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-features-2)

**Goal:** as a "server admin" (actually a CS teacher with very little sysadmin experience using containers for educational purposes), I would like to create a *single* shared image and allow multiple users to run that shared image. This way, we do not end up with many identical copies (think 100s of students *pulling* an image copy as an alternative) of the *same* image for every user, but every user can easily make use of an identical containerized setup.

**My attempt:**

I was able to get most of the way there, I believe. However, in the end, neither the `serveradmin` account nor the typical user, e.g. `user01`, can run the share image.

This is what happened on a completely fresh install of Ubuntu Server.

First, while logged in as `serveradmin`, typical update stuff

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo apt update 
serveradmin@testserver> sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Next, install `podman` and test that it works

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo apt install podman
serveradmin@testserver> podman run hello-world # worked perfectly
```

Expecting to see just the hello-world image. Yep, works.

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman images
REPOSITORY                     TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
docker.io/library/hello-world  latest      feb5d9fea6a5  13 months ago  19.9 kB
```

Create shared storage location for all users to access images

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo mkdir /var/lib/shared-storage
```

Pull my `pmtest` ("podman test") image from DockerHub into the *shared* location

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman --root /var/lib/shared-storage pull docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest
```

Look for the pulled image, it is not visible yet, as expected

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman images
REPOSITORY                     TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
docker.io/library/hello-world  latest      feb5d9fea6a5  13 months ago  19.9 kB
```

Create a storage config for the `serveradmin`

```
serveradmin@testserver> mkdir ~/.config/containers/
serveradmin@testserver> vim .config/containers/storage.conf
serveradmin@testserver> cat ~/.config/containers/storage.conf 
[storage]
driver = "overlay"
[storage.options]
additionalimagestores = [ "/var/lib/shared-storage"]
```

`serveradmin` user cannot read `/var/lib/shared-storage/*` in order to list images

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman images
Error: error opening "/var/lib/shared-storage/overlay-images/images.lock": permission denied
```

Using `sudo`, can't see any images, not even the previously visible `hello-world` image

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo podman images
REPOSITORY  TAG         IMAGE ID    CREATED     SIZE
```

So, make `/var/lib/shared-storage` world-readable and world-executable, is this OK to do?

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo chmod +r -R /var/lib/shared-storage/
serveradmin@testserver> sudo chmod +x -R /var/lib/shared-storage/
```

Now the images are indeed visible to the `serveradmin` user

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman images
REPOSITORY                     TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED         SIZE        R/O
docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest     latest      824fec7db82a  16 minutes ago  262 MB      true
docker.io/library/hello-world  latest      feb5d9fea6a5  13 months ago   19.9 kB     false
```

However, cannot run the image, several different attempts

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman run pmtest
Error: creating /etc/mtab symlink: permission denied
```

```
serveradmin@testserver> podman run docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest:latest 
Error: creating /etc/mtab symlink: permission denied
```

Cannot run when using `sudo` either

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo podman run pmtest
Error: short-name "pmtest" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"
```

Using `sudo podman run` pulls the image rather than running the shared image. This is not what I want.

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo podman run docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest:latest 
Trying to pull docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob cf92e523b49e done  
Copying blob d59e8b19e2b2 [====================>-----------------] 37.2MiB / 68.6MiB
```

What about another user? This is the end goal anyway, so create another standard user

```
serveradmin@testserver> sudo useradd user01
serveradmin@testserver> sudo passwd user01
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Signed in as `user01`, cannot see any images

```
user01@testserver> podman images
REPOSITORY  TAG         IMAGE ID    CREATED     SIZE
```

Create the additional image store config for `user01`, just like before

```
user01@testserver> micro .config/containers/storage.conf
user01@testserver> cat ~/.config/containers/storage.conf 
[storage]
driver = "overlay"
[storage.options]
additionalimagestores = [ "/var/lib/shared-storage"]
```

Now, `user01` can indeed see the shared image

```
user01@testserver> podman images
REPOSITORY                  TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED      SIZE        R/O
docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest  latest      824fec7db82a  5 hours ago  262 MB      true
```

But, `user01` still cannot run the image, same issues as `serveradmin`, except can't even use `sudo`

```
user01@testserver> podman run pmtest
Error: creating /etc/mtab symlink: permission denied
user01@testserver> podman run docker.io/<my_dockerhub>/pmtest:latest
Error: creating /etc/mtab symlink: permission denied
user01@pmtestserver:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have missed a couple of critical steps. I'm going to walk through the process on my own Ubuntu 22.04.1 system, and let's see where we end up.

I'm going to start right after having installed `podman`. First, let's see what version we get:

```
root@ubuntu:~# podman version
Version:      3.4.4
API Version:  3.4.4
Go Version:   go1.17.3
Built:        Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Well, that's a disappointment. Podman 4 was released in August 2021. It's possible we'll hit features that aren't implemented in this version (although the first article to which you linked was published in 2020, so we ought to be okay on that account) or bugs that have been fixed in more recent versions, but let's try it anyway!

### Creating the shared image store

This is going to look *remarkably* similar to what you've tried :).

1. We need a directory for our shared storage:

   ```
   mkdir /var/lib/shared-storage
   ```
2. Let's populate that with an image:

   ```
   podman --root /var/lib/shared-storage pull docker.io/alpine:latest
   ```
3. We know *that* worked because we can see the image when using the `--root` option:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# podman --root /var/lib/shared-storage/ image ls
   REPOSITORY                TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
   docker.io/library/alpine  latest      9c6f07244728  2 months ago  5.83 MB
   ```
4. Now we need to configure the `additionalimagestores` option in `/etc/containers/storage.conf`:

   ```
   [storage]
   driver = "overlay"
   graphroot = "/var/lib/containers/storage"

   [storage.options]
   additionalimagestores = ["/var/lib/shared-storage"]
   ```

   (That `graphroot` option is there because without it `podman` will constantly yell about it being unset.)
5. With that configuration in place -- *and no other changes* -- we see that it works for `podman` running as `root`:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# podman image ls
   REPOSITORY                TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE        R/O
   docker.io/library/alpine  latest      9c6f07244728  2 months ago  5.83 MB     true
   ```

   Note that we see the additional `R/O` column in that output, indicating that `podman` is reading from our `additionalimagestores`.
6. Still running as `root`, we can launch a container from that image:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# podman run --rm docker.io/alpine:latest cat /etc/os-release
   NAME="Alpine Linux"
   ID=alpine
   VERSION_ID=3.16.2
   PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.16"
   HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"
   ```

   You can see it didn't need to pull the image because it already exists in the shared location.

### Accessing the shared image store as an unprivileged user

Now that we have things working for `root`, let's get it working for an unprivileged user. I've created a test user like this:

```
useradd -m -c "Test User 001" user001
```

1. Become the test user<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   su - user001
   ```
2. Create `$HOME/.config/containers/storage.conf` as:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.config/containers
   cat > ~/.config/containers/storage.conf <<EOF
   [storage]
   driver = "overlay"

   [storage.options]
   additionalimagestores = ["/var/lib/shared-storage"]

   [storage.options.overlay]
   mount_program = "/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs"
   EOF
   ```

   That last bit -- setting `storage.options.overlay.mount_program` -- is critical (and comes straight from that first article to which you linked).
3. Attempt to access the new image store...

   ```
   podman image ls
   ```

   ...and watch it fail:

   ```
   Error: error opening "/var/lib/shared-storage/overlay-images/images.lock": permission denied
   ```
4. Grant read access to everything (and execute access to directories) in `/var/lib/shared-storage`. **As `root`**, run:

   ```
   chmod -R a+rX /var/lib/shared-storage/
   ```
5. Return to the `user001` account and re-try our `podman` command:

   ```
   user001@ubuntu:~$ podman image ls
   REPOSITORY                TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE        R/O
   docker.io/library/alpine  latest      9c6f07244728  2 months ago  5.83 MB     true
   ```
6. Verify things are working by running a container:

   ```
   user001@ubuntu:~$ podman run --rm docker.io/alpine:latest cat /etc/os-release
   NAME="Alpine Linux"
   ID=alpine
   VERSION_ID=3.16.2
   PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.16"
   HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"
   ```

And that's it! If you see different behavior at any point in this process, let me know and I'll see what we can figure out.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that in order to get this step to work and stop `podman` from complainining, I had to `loginctl enable-linger 1000` and `systemctl start user@1000.service`. This is only necessary because we're using `su`; if we were logging in via `ssh` or via the local console this wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Instead of `su - user001` you could use `machinectl shell user001@`. I think that is the preferred way when using Podman. _"The answer is that sudo and su do not create a login session"_ quote from https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman  Another quote "_It's not a tool for opening a completely new login session._" from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237

Comment: Yes! This did the trick. Worked exactly as expected. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @larsks, followup question. Why does every user need to have their own ~/.config/containers/storage.conf file? Is it not possible for there to be a global storage.conf that sets this up for all users?

Comment: I don't know why podman operates that way; that's a question for the podman developers.

Comment: OK, thanks! perhaps I will try looking further into it. For now in any case, things are working :)

Comment: storage.conf supports configuring a forced permissions mask so that you don't need to chmod after pull - https://github.com/containers/storage/blob/main/docs/containers-storage.conf.5.md#storage-options-for-overlay-table - but I can't seem to get this to work. Once you use --root that settings seems to not be in effect.